# How can I import Vimeo.js library into my Angular 2 with Typescript app?

Tags: angular

I want to import Vimeo.js module (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js) in my Angular 2 Typescript app.

What is the equivalent to `var Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;`? How can I import it?

It would be great to see an example using it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
declare var Vimeo: {};
Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
```

Comment: That produces another error: `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.` in the line I write: `var lib = new Vimeo(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN);`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, with Typescript 3.7, this worked:

```typescript
const Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;

const client = new Vimeo(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN);
```